# Smoothwall web proxy VM blocks CSS files from CDNs

Tags: proxy, cdn, smoothwall

We have a Smoothwall web proxy set up as a virtual machine for internet browsing.

When a site hosts CSS files on a CDN (probably any cross-domain request actually) the CSS isn't applied, indicating that Smoothwall is filtering it out.

I am not familiar enough with Smoothwall web proxy to determine if and which setting could affect this. I know that in GFI Webmonitor (a similar software), one can configure Internet Policies for filtering content, and a General Interest > CDN policy controls whether CDNs are blocked or not.

I know that I could try to put sites manually onto a whitelist but with more and more content being served from a CDN, this defeats the purpose of the web proxy filter. It should go through the filter and have its content checked but not being blacklisted - it seems that it is point blank refused (how can CSS files be content which should be filtered out?)

Anyone knows how to configure Smoothwall to avoid the CDN blocking?